# Priority of two NSOutlineView delegates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nsoutlineview

For tests and understanding delegates, I'm changing two times the color of a NSCell in

```
- (NSCell *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
 dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {

    if (tableColumn == nil)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    [cell setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell
     forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {

    [cell setTextColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
}
```

*dataCellForTableColumn:* is called first, but the color keeps red, also I see in the debugger the property's change in *willDisplayCell*. This second delegate doesn't seem to modify my cell.

If I call only *willDisplayCell*, the text is ok, in Blue.

Comment: Reference for the 1st method indicates it's called twice, first time with a nil column, so that could be an issue.  But the bigger issue would seem to be that the reference for the 2nd method says it "is not safe to do any drawing in this method."  The return type for the 2nd method is also void.

Comment: While the second method says you can't do drawing, it still allows modifying the cell's properties. You're right about the rest of your comments. It's probably related to not checking for 'nil' in `dataCell` method.

Comment: @JacobGorban - yes, you're right.  re-reading the OP says it's ***text*** color, while I was thinking it was the background color, which I thought might count as "drawing."  In any event, supplying the code would help show both things... whether `nil` is checked, and that it is text color.

Comment: I've corrected with the right code, I'm handling nil, and the 2nd method returns void of course. Can you reproduce this behavior?